# Manually set an authenticated user in Spring Security with LDAP

Tags: authentication, spring-security, spring-ldap

I know how to set an authenticated manually:

```
Authentication authentication =  new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, person.getAuthorities());
```

But because I use LDAP, the "user" variable must be a LdapUserDetails, how can I create a LdapUserDetails instance with input is a username string?

Comment: You can create your own ```LDAPUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService``` which will produce your own ```LDAPUserDetails implements UserDetails```. And then put it to ```DaoAuthenticationProvider```. Then in spring-security configuration ```AuthenticationManagerBuilder#authenticationProvider()```. If you don't want to create it by hand, there is already infrastructure in spring-security http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.1.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/userdetails/package-summary.html

Comment: @Mati: The LdapUserDetails class exists, I want to create an instance of that class.